# clear() function does not erase the default value of input web element

Tags: java, selenium, testing, selenium-webdriver

I am a very beginner to use Java and Selenium to write a test.
I have this web element:

```
   <input type="number" name="yield_target" 
placeholder="Yield Target" value="0.00" min="0" step="any">
```

But I can not clear it by:

```
WebElement we =  wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated
(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Yield Target']")));
we.clear();
```

But I can write into it, for example if I use:

```
action.sendKeys(we, "223").build().perform();
```

it will be 0.00223 instead of 223.

Comment: I guess, when you clear your field you will see the text value of your placeholder. It does not help to clear the field because it just clear the value of the field and you will see the value of placeholder. If you don't want to see this you should remove placeholder attribute.

Comment: @CyberAleks what did you mean by "value of your placeholder"?

Comment: @CyberAleks, A DOMElement's value is independent of its placeholder attribute.

Comment: I mean, do you see "Yield Target" after clear?

Comment: @CyberAleks there is no "Yield Target", we have "0.00" in the text box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why `we.clear()` isn't working but you can clear and set in a single call (assuming that JavaScript on the page does not prevent you from using CTRL+A to select all of the contents of the number input field):

```
we.sendKeys(Keys.chord(Keys.CONTROL, "a"), "223");
```